# How to resolve the handler and the method dynamically from the headers?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

My flow is like this

```
private IntegrationFlow myChannel() {
    return f -> f
            ...
            .handle("myHandler", "myMethod")
            ...
}
```

How to resolve the handler `myHandler` and the method `myMethod` dynamically from the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.router()` with subflows for each header value.

Comment: See my answer. Not sure though that it is so legitimate way to abuse dependency injection :-)

Comment: Thanks. I think the `.router()` method is the best and standard way to handle this, but it's also good to know the `MethodInvokingMessageProcessor` method.

Answer (score 1):

We need to understand first of all what is the purpose of such a business logic.

I think we can achieve your requirements with this code:

```
.handle((p, h) -> 
        new MethodInvokingMessageProcessor(h.get("myHandler"), h.get("myMethod", String.class)
                        .processMessage(new GenericMessage<>(p, h))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The purpose is that I have implemented the integration application, which integrates the REST services. The services have different types of the authentication (the Basic, the api key, custom etc.) and I wanted to have the different authentication sub classes for the different authentication types. Those classes all have same goal to set the `Authorization` header.